# AOP without Spring

Tags: java, logging, aop, aspect

I implemented Logger using Spring 4.0 and AspectJ. But I'm now trying to make the logger independent of Spring. I couldn't initialize aspect in my application. Any hint to start will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a Spring- based app and you want to use AspectJ, it is better to use the AspectJ features offered by Spring. You can also use Spring AOP without AspectJ.

You can make cross-cutting functionality by using AspectJ annotations with Spring AOP.

[`@Aspect`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-introduction-defn) annotation allow you to make the aspect from your `Logger` class.

In the `Logger` class define set of the pointcut by using the [`@Pointcut`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-pointcuts) annotation. By using annotations [`@Before`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-advice-before), [`@AfterReturning`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-advice-after-returning), [`@AfterThrowing`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-advice-after-throwing) define the advices and when they will be applied relative to the set of the pointcut (before, after, in the case of throwing an exception).

Then include the `aop` namespace in Spring configuration file and register the object of the class `AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator` by using [`<aop:aspectj-autoproxy>`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-proxying.) configuration element.

This component also performs proxying of classes which have `@Aspect` annotation  and which have methods included in a certain set of the pointcut.

How to use AspectJ without Spring you can find here, for example: 
[Using AspectJ logging without Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938487/using-aspectj-logging-without-spring)

Comment: Thank you so much @Aleksey. The example really worked. Thanks for the appropriate answer.

Comment: May I ask why don't you want to use Spring?  Are you trying to use your library in a JakartaEE project?  Or?